# persistência de dados em dois ou mais bancos simultâneamente

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Saudações!

Gostaria que alguém me ajudasse com algum exemplo de uma aplicação JSF que persistisse dados simultâneamente em mais de um banco, ou seja: se conectará há 2+ bancos e injetará dados nestes.

Estou usando Hibernate.

O projeto está em: https://github.com/felippefloriani/buildsoft

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Já, consegui!

Se alguém estiver com a mesma dúvida, vou compartilhar aqui minha solução:

1. Além do hibernate.cfg.xml, criei outro arquivo que chamei de hibernate1.cfg.xml no qual incluo a sessionfactory do outro banco. 
   OBS: Em meu projeto,o primeiro hibernate.cfg.xml é para o MySQL e, o segundo, para o PostgreSQL.
2. No pacote br.com.meuprojeto.util eu já tinha a classe HibernateUtil.java. Então, criei outra classe, desta vez HibernateUtil1.java cuja implementação segue:

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil1 {

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

    try {
        // Cria SessionFactory a partir do hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Falha ao tentar criar o SessionFactory." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

3. Dentro do meu pacote br.com.meuprojeto.main, tenho a classe GeraTabela.java com o método main chamando as duas classes HibernateUtil e HibernateUtil1, como segue:

public class GeraTabela {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();

    HibernateUtil1.getSessionFactory();
    HibernateUtil1.getSessionFactory().close();

}
```

}

Pode não ser a solução mais elegante. Mas executei esta classe e lá estavam as tabelas criadas em ambos os bancos.

Valeu a quem acompanhou!